# How to return a non-copyable, movable object by-value as const and store it?

Tags: c++

```
class A;
const A getA();
```

A - non-copyable, movable.

`getA()` - constructs and returns an `A`, as `const`.

How to do this?

```
const A a = getA();
```

I can only do this.

```
const A& a = getA();
```

Answer (score 10):

Don't return by value as `const`. When you return anything you are saying "Here caller, this is yours now. Do what you want with it". If the caller of your method doesn't want to modify it, they can store it as `const`, as you have shown above with: `const A a = getA();`. But you (as a method) shouldn't be telling the caller whether *their* objects are `const` or not (your return value is *their* object).

If your return value is `const` you can't `move` from it into your new object, so your move constructor is not even considered. The only option is copying, which doesn't work either because in your case it's a noncopyable object. If the return is non-const you can move from it, and you get the behavior you want.

Comment: This is good general advice: when returning by value, don't make the value const.  It usually won't help you.